# How do I make circles that touch each other and their centers lies on one circle in tkinter pyton?

Tags: python, tkinter, math, trigonometry

I have program where you enter word and it should make as many circles as the word has letters. Circles should also touch each other, not overlap, and thier centers should lie on circle and are equidistant.

```
import tkinter
from math import sin, cos 
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

label=tkinter.Label(text='enter word')
label.pack()

entry=tkinter.Entry()
entry.pack()

def draw():
    canvas.delete('all')
    word=entry.get()
    n=len(word)
    angle=360/n 
    for i in range(n):
        x=sin(angle*i)*90
        y=cos(angle*i)*90
        canvas.create_oval(x+200,y+200,x+300,y+300)
        canvas.create_text(x+250,y+250, text=word[i])
        
button=tkinter.Button(text='draw', command=draw)
button.pack()
```

Comment: Aside from the open-ended one in the title, you don't seem to have a question in your question. Please read [ask].

Comment: this may need to use complex Math calculation

Comment: ask question inside question's body.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to calculate the required radius of those circles which is half the length between points of drawing the text:

```py
import tkinter
from math import sin, cos, pi

...

def draw():
    canvas.delete('all')
    word = entry.get()
    n = len(word)
    angle = pi * 2 / n  # need to use radian instead of degree
    points = []   # use to store calculated points
    for i in range(n):
        x = sin(angle*i) * 90
        y = cos(angle*i) * 90
        # draw the character
        canvas.create_text(x+250, y+250, text=word[i])
        points.append((x, y)) # save the points for drawing circles later

    # calculate the radius of the circles using the first two points
    dx, dy = points[1][0]-points[0][0], points[1][1]-points[0][1]
    r = (dx*dx + dy*dy) ** 0.5 / 2

    # draw the circles
    for x, y in points:
        canvas.create_oval(250+x-r, 250+y-r, 250+x+r, 250+y+r)
```

The result:

[image]